# Unable to add ContentPage in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

[image]

Are there any solution to this one? Searching google only gave 3 results and no possible solution. I updated my VS 2019 Preview to the latest version - Preview 2 due to P1 is having an issue with the DLL being used by another process and XF GitHub said, it was fixed in P2. It was fixed alright but it introduced a new painful error. I cannot add a ContentPage, event ContentView. I can add .cs, but .xaml.

Does anyone has a solution for this one?

Comment: A simple solution ... I will be adding ContentPage or View in Visual Studio 2017, then conntinue working on VS 2019 Pro Prev 2. :P That's what I'm going to do for now.

Comment: Please open the VS installer,click the `Repair`, If this issue is disappear.

Comment: Are there any update for this issue?

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT - I thought "Repair" only means the installer will repair some invalid configurations

Comment: This is what Repair looks like https://www.screencast.com/t/5ahNMawJ4JER

Comment: You have to update the VS to the latest version, then you can repair it like this screenshot.https://imgur.com/a/XImJuq0

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT - I am already using the latest 2019 Preview version. That was updated 2 days before posting this issue.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT and yes, I clicked that REPAIR menu

Comment: If this issue is still existed, you can open a free case:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=211dd84f-3474-c3c5-79bf-66db630c92a6 , supporter will connect to you remotely